# nodejs module throws error but same code worked in main js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I want to know why this custom module is not working

module:

```
var mariadb = require('mariadb');

class DB{
    constructor(){
        this.db_conn = null;
        this.db_pool = mariadb.createPool({
            host:"localhost",
            user:"root",
            password:"",
            database:"testdatabse"
        });
        this.db_pool.getConnection().then(conn => {
            this.db_conn = conn;
        });
    }
};


module.exports = function(){
    return (new DB()).db_conn;
}
```

but the same code working in main javascript file

main file here:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var mariadb = require('mariadb');
var dbs = require('./modules/mariadb-connector'); //here i am importing the module
var db_conn;
var db = mariadb.createPool({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"testdatabase"
});
db.getConnection().then(conn => {
    db_conn = conn;
});

console.log(dbs.query("SELECT * FROM array_languages")); //here it's throwing error

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    console.log(req.url);
    db_conn.query("SELECT * FROM array_languages").then(data => {
        res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(8080,"localhost");
```

error:

```
PS D:\Programs\nodejs\test> node index.js
D:\Programs\nodejs\test\index.js:16
console.log(dbs.query("SELECT * FROM array_languages"));
                ^

TypeError: dbs.query is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Programs\nodejs\test\index.js:16:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

here the error when I tried to use this module

at `console.log(dbs.query("SELECT * FROM array_languages"));`

please explain why is working in main js file but not in module.
is there any way to achieve this

Comment: @DDiamond sorry not worked

Comment: says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null`

Comment: Try `module.exports = new DB()` and then replace the require with `var dbs = require('./modules/mariadb-connector').db_conn;`

Comment: @DDiamond throwing same error

Comment: I think the code is not initializing at the time of `console.log(dbs.query("SELECT * FROM array_languages"));` execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dbs = require('./modules/mariadb-connector')
```

sets `dbs` to the exports object of the custom module, which is a function to return a connector to a new db:

```
function(){
    return (new DB()).db_conn;
}
```

You could try calling the exports module when setting `dbs` like

```
var dbs = require('./modules/mariadb-connector')();
```

However, this leave the problem that the `.db_conn` property of `new DB()` is set asynchronously in a promise callback. Immediately after requiring the module `db-conn` in the module will still be `null`.

Some form of asynchronous processing needs to be implemented,  *taking into consideration that at the moment there is a race condition* between getting the database connection and servicing a request to look up the database. At the moment setting up the connection wins the race: this is the only reason it appears to work when the connection code is in the main module.

An Outline of asynchronous processing for ideas:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var mariadb = require('mariadb');

async function db_conn() {
    let db_pool  = mariadb.createPool({
            host:"localhost",
            user:"root",
            password:"",
            database:"testdatabse"
        });

    const conn = await db_pool.getConnection();
    return conn;
}

db_conn().then( db_conn => {

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        console.log(req.url);
        db_conn.query("SELECT * FROM array_languages").then(data => {
            res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
            res.end();
        });
    }).listen(8080,"localhost");

})
.catch( err=> {
   console.error( err));
   process.exit(1);
});
```

Comment: I was about to edit my answer, had missed the function exported not being called

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not the same code, is it? Your problem is here:

```
        this.db_pool.getConnection().then(conn => {
            this.db_conn = conn;
        });
```

This is an async function. It will finish running after the constructor has run. You're importing `return (new DB()).db_conn` when `db_conn` is `null`.

If you're set on using it as a class, I'd create a method `getConnection` that got the value from `db_conn` after it has finished running, and import the instance instead of the the property